# confirming this will blink LED at given frequency

Tags: programming, led

I want to blink an LED at an specific frequency, ie: 7Hz

here what Im doing

```
int ledPin = 4;
float freq = 7;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

float periodo() {
  float peri = 1/freq;
  float halfer = peri/2;
  float millisec = halfer*1000;
  return millisec;
  //return ((1/freq)/2)*1000;
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);    
  delay(periodo());                       
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);     
  delay(periodo());                       
}
```

Is this correct? is that the best way to do it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: In addition to the answer: I would not call  `periodo` in the loop if the `freq` does not change. Use a global `int actPeriod` variable and only initialize it in the setup function with ` actPeriod=periodo(freq);` and every time the preq variable might change (in comming revisions ;-)). Then use the new variable in the delay. With the actual code there would be no problems, but you asked for optimal code and if you add time criutial functionallity, it could matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if it is correct by timing it for one minute and check if it is (approximately) ok.

However, I see a few improvements:

- First is that you always return 1/7/2*1000 = 71.429, which is rounded down to 71. 71 * 14 = 994 ms so you get a bit faster speed than 7 Hz. if this is a problem you have to compensate for this.
- Another small problem is that you `delay`, but the `digitalWrite` commands also take some time which is not included for the delays. So you need also to take this into account when using a precise delay.
- When using floats I always use float constant numbers, like 1.0 and 7.0 instead of 1 and 7. This can especially be useful when you divide two integers (e.g. 1/7), which results in 0.14 this is rounded down to 0 as it is an int.

The best you can do is using the `millis` command. You keep a timer and compare it to the current `millis` value. If it is too high, do a state change. This will take into account every other method you do meanwhile the `digitalWrite`s.

Something like: (code fixed due to EdgarBonet's remarks)

```
const float FREQ = 7.0; // Hz
const int PIN_NR = 4;

unsigned long _startTime;
unsigned long _counter;

int _currentState = LOW;

void setup() 
{
  _startTime = millis();
  _counter = 0;
  _currentState = LOW;
  digitalWrite(PIN_NR, _currentState);
}

void loop() 
{
  if (_startTime + _counter * 1000.0 / FREQ / 2.0 >= millis())
  {
    _counter++;
    _currentState = ~_currentState;
    digitalWrite(PIN_NR, _currentState);
  }
}
```

Some small notes:

- _currentState is the current state of the LED, with ~ you can flip it (it's called the `not` operator).
- _startTime is the (close to zero) value of the `millis` value at startup.
- Take in mind there is a limit how long this app can run or precise. `millis` works with ms, meaning you cannot get beyond 500 Hz, and you get 'approximations' with frequencies below in some cases. E.g. when Freq = 80 Hz, you get 1000 * 1 / 80 / 2 = 1000 / 160 = 6.25 => 6, which is actually 1000/6/2=83.3 Hz.
- Also the counter is added once per state change, and because of 1000 * _counter ... an overflow exists when _counter >= 256 * 256 * 256 * 256 / 1000 = about 4 million. With 1000 state changes per second, this happens after 4000 seconds, which is 66 minutes. For 7 Hz it will not occur fast.

Comment: 1. This will make each interval 71 ms longer than the previous one, which means the frequency is modulated down towards zero. 2. This is prone to a rollover bug. Avoiding the bug is as easy as following the Blink Without Delay tutorial, so there is no good reason to keep the bug. 3. If you call `millis()` twice in a single loop iteration, you could very well get different results, in which case your timing calculations are off. Call `millis()` once and record the value if you need it twice. 4. Why these irritating underscores in front of every single variable name?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for your comments. 1 was indeed a stupid bug. 2. The Blink without delay tutorial is not exactly precise as the interval is a fixed value. It could be improved with some compensation though without having my 1000 multiplication resulting in a rollover. 3. Good point, I changed it in my code. 4 Not in every variable name, only 'global/class' variables, to make clear these are not local variables.